# Blender 2.9 Could not find a matching GPU name warning on Chromebook

Tags: blender, chromebook

I'm using an Asus Chromebook with a CPU(I think).
This is what the Error says:

> Warning: Could not find a matching GPU name. Things may not behave as expected.
> Detected OpenGL configuration:
> Vendor: Red Hat
> Renderer: virgl
> /run/user/1000/gvfs/ non-existent directory
> found bundled python: /home/sekhong5417/blender/2.90/python

This works on my Friend's Chromebook who has a GPU.

Also I am kinda young so I can't replace anything or buy a new device.

There are images at the bottom

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Hey @Gurshan, I think you accidentally left out the images you said you attached.
Also, I think the issue stems from a version of python that Blender attempts to use which is not your system's python, therefore it can't access the GPU.
Try uninstalling Blender and then following [this](https://chromeunboxed.com/three-ways-to-install-blender-3d-software-on-your-chromebook/) guide.

Comment: That is what I used to install blender. I used the third way. What Version of Python do I need? Thank You!

Comment: Also I'm sure I uploaded the images it posted a link, Here are the Images on Google Docs. https://docs.google.com/document/d/1dzpDk_qov32s_BzwxAz56OrSbU6gozy547Jygd53LNI/edit?ts=5f5fd915

Comment: 2.82a seems to be the newest version which works on many chromebooks.  You can get 2.82a here:  https://download.blender.org/release/Blender2.82/blender-2.82a-linux64.tar.xz

Answer (score 2):

If anyone still runs into this issue, there is an incompatibility with Blender and Intel ChromeOS GPU drivers.

See https://developer.blender.org/T77651#1172666 for more details and an updated working build of v2.93.

Hopefully, the fix gets included in the next release.

Answer (score 1):

I use Acer Chromebook spin 13 and I just met the same issue with you. I think it is maybe the Debian within Chromebook don't have the driver that matches the Intel GPU. My Chromebook uses Intel HD graphics 620. I tried many ways to install the driver but they all failed. Linux works easier with Nvidia GPU though. So my idea is you can try to find intel a drive which matches your Graphic card and try again.

Comment: I've written in the question that i can't replace anything, but blender 2.81 might work bc i had it before.